How to use protoc command to decode multiple files?
I have two proto files at different file paths ->
path1/a.proto
path2/b.proto
i use the command:
protoc --decode="packagename" path1/a.proto < dump.pb > dump.txt

And the output file isn't able to decode it properly (positions instead of the property name) ->
enter image description here
The a.proto file imports b.proto file in its imports section. Still facing the issue. Is there a way to fix this?
I tried looking for this problem on the official documentation of protoc but couldn't get a solution for this.

The syntax for --decode is --decode some_message_name, where some_message_name is a type defined in your .proto files - no =, and packages != messages; this doesn't match your example - can you confirm?

Note that some_message_name can be fully.qualified.with.dots

Possibly best explained through an example:
We model 2 distinct protobuf paths (path1,path2) each contains a distinct package (packagex,packagey) with similarly named protobufs (see below)
.
├── path1
│   └── packagex
│       └── packagex.proto
└── path2
    └── packagey
        └── packagey.proto

Where:
packagex.proto:
syntax = "proto3";

package packagex;

import "packagey/packagey.proto";

// Replace {MODULE} with you go module path
option go_package="{MODULE}/packagex";

message P1 {
    string id = 1;
    packagey.P2 p2 = 2; 
}

packagey.proto:
syntax = "proto3";

package packagey;

// Replace {MODULE} with you go module path
option go_package="{MODULE}/packagey";

message P2 {
    string id = 1;
}

packagex contains P1 defined to include (import) packagey.P2
We can compile to Go sources:
MODULE="..." # Your Go module path

PATH1=${PWD}/path1
PATH2=${PWD}/path2

protoc \
--proto_path=${PATH1} \
--proto_path=${PATH2} \
--go_out=${PWD} \
--go_opt=module=${MODULE} \
--go-grpc_out=${PWD} \
--go-grpc_opt=module=${MODULE} \
${PATH1}/packagex/packagex.proto \
${PATH2}/packagey/packagey.proto


NOTE there are 2 distinct protobuf paths (path1,path2) which must distinctly --proto_path refrerenced. Thereafter (!) we must reference package-scoped protobufs according to these i.e. ${PATH2}/packagey/packagey.proto.

Yields:
.
├── packagex
│   └── packagex.pb.go
├── packagey
│   └── packagey.pb.go
├── path1
│   └── packagex
│       └── packagex.proto
└── path2
    └── packagey
        └── packagey.proto


NOTE Generated Go sources don't reference the protobuf paths but retain the reference to the packages. This is user-defined behavior.

Generate an example message file:
package main

import (
    "log/slog"
    "os"

    // Replace {MODULE} with your go module path
    "{MODULE}/packagex"
    "{MODULE}/packagey"

    "google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"
)

func main() {
    p1 := &packagex.P1{
        Id: "foo",
        P2: &packagey.P2{
            Id: "bar",
        },
    }
    m, err := proto.Marshal(p1)
    if err != nil {
        slog.Error("unable to marshall message", "err", err)
    }

    slog.Info("Message", "m", m)
    if err := os.WriteFile("p1.pb", m, 0644); err != nil {
        slog.Error("unable to write file", "err", err)
    }
}

Yields p1.pb:
0a03666f6f12050a03626172

And lastly:
protoc \
--proto_path=${PATH1} \
--proto_path=${PATH2} \
--decode=packagex.P1 \
${PATH1}/packagex/packagex.proto < p1.pb

id: "foo"
p2 {
  id: "bar"
}


NOTE

References both proto_path's as we did to generate sources
--decode is the fully-qualified package.Message name
References the fully-qualified file path to packagex.proto



Hey, thanks for sharing this detailed answer! It worked for me!

You're welcome! I'm glad it helped.
